# CKAN unintentional additional DataPusher jobs being triggered on resource update

Tags: python, postgresql, ckan

I'm using CKAN 2.2.1 with the DataStore and DataPusher plugins. Almost all of our data is updated via an import script which checks an FTP directory periodically and matches files against resources in CKAN.

We update the files each time a new one is found by matching on resource ID. These are then automatically added to the DataStore by the DataPusher plugin after the `update_resource` API request has been sent.

I'm logging cURL request used to send these `update_resource` request to confirm we are sending requests exactly as expected and everything looks fine.

What seems to be happening when we are updating a resource in a dataset with multiple resources is that DataPusher adds a job to update the resource we've just updated, but then 2-3 seconds later adds another job for a random resource within the dataset. This is often another resource we are about to update, or even the resource we just updated.

This results in overlapping jobs of the same resource being updated in the datastore and causes errors, since the same tables are being updated at the same time.

I've confirmed we are not mistakenly sending multiple update request via my cURL logs, however if I was to make three `update_resource` requests, DataPusher will update 5 or 6 resources immediately after. This is always the resource we expect, followed by another random resource.

I can see in the datapusher access logs it has been triggered more than three times:

In this particular instance I updated three resources, footfalldaily, footfallhourly and footfall weekly. With three `update_resource` requests.

This is the resulting access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:20:04 +0100] "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64" **0/65095** rx:514 tx:665
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:20:09 +0100] "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64" **0/182644** rx:514 tx:665
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:20:12 +0100] "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64" **0/138258** rx:514 tx:665
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:20:16 +0100] "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64" **0/137663** rx:514 tx:665
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2015:17:20:19 +0100] "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "python-requests/1.1.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64" **0/118033** rx:514 tx:665
```

And this is the resulting error log, showing random update happening immediately after, and the resulting errors from overlapping updates to the same file:

Any suggestions as to why this extra DataPusher jobs are being triggered?

```
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:04 2015] [error] Fetching from: http://hidden-domain.com/dataset/6449d8f5-76e7-4aff-bfb1-46d46542a56c/resource/b9cde552-ff7a-41c3-b6e6-1f16a80a09eb/download/footfalldaily.csv
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:05 2015] [error] Deleting "b9cde552-ff7a-41c3-b6e6-1f16a80a09eb" from datastore.
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:05 2015] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'timestamp', 'id': u'Date'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'SiteName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationGroup'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'WeekDay'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCYear'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCQuarter'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCMonth'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCWeek'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'InCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'OutCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'TotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessTotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredTotalCount'}]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:06 2015] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:06 2015] [error] Saving chunk 1
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:07 2015] [error] Saving chunk 2
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:07 2015] [error] Saving chunk 3
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:08 2015] [error] Saving chunk 4
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:08 2015] [error] Saving chunk 5
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:09 2015] [error] Saving chunk 6
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:09 2015] [error] Saving chunk 7
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:09 2015] [error] Fetching from: http://hidden-domain.com/dataset/6449d8f5-76e7-4aff-bfb1-46d46542a56c/resource/b9cde552-ff7a-41c3-b6e6-1f16a80a09eb/download/footfalldaily.csv
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:10 2015] [error] Saving chunk 8
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:10 2015] [error] Deleting "b9cde552-ff7a-41c3-b6e6-1f16a80a09eb" from datastore.
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'timestamp', 'id': u'Date'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'SiteName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationGroup'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'WeekDay'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCYear'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCQuarter'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCMonth'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCWeek'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'InCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'OutCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'TotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessTotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredTotalCount'}]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 321, in push_to_datastore
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     records, api_key, ckan_url)
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 150, in send_resource_to_datastore
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     check_response(r, url, 'CKAN DataStore')
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 91, in check_response
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     resp=response.text[:200]))
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] JobError: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 500 Internal Server Error. At: http://hidden-domain.com/api/3/action/datastore_create. Response:
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     <html>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     <head>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     <title>Server Error</title>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     </head>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     <body>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     <h1>Server Error</h1>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     An internal server error occurred
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     </body>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error]     </html>
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Saving chunk 1
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:11 2015] [error] Saving chunk 2
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:12 2015] [error] Fetching from: http://hidden-domain.com/dataset/6449d8f5-76e7-4aff-bfb1-46d46542a56c/resource/8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a/download/footfallhourly.csv
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:12 2015] [error] Saving chunk 3
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:12 2015] [error] Saving chunk 4
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Saving chunk 5
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Deleting "8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a" from datastore.
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'Id'}, {'type': u'timestamp', 'id': u'Date'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'SiteName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationGroup'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'WeekDay'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCYear'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCQuarter'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCMonth'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCWeek'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'InCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'OutCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'TotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessTotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredTotalCount'}]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Saving chunk 6
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:14 2015] [error] Saving chunk 1
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:15 2015] [error] Saving chunk 7
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:15 2015] [error] Saving chunk 2
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:16 2015] [error] Saving chunk 8
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:16 2015] [error] Saving chunk 3
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:16 2015] [error] Saving chunk 9
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:16 2015] [error] Fetching from: http://hidden-domain.com/dataset/6449d8f5-76e7-4aff-bfb1-46d46542a56c/resource/8ae0a0b0-eee6-4062-8ef8-13f3177519ff/download/footfallweekly.csv
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:17 2015] [error] Saving chunk 10
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:17 2015] [error] Saving chunk 4
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:17 2015] [error] Deleting "8ae0a0b0-eee6-4062-8ef8-13f3177519ff" from datastore.
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:17 2015] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'text', 'id': u'SiteName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationGroup'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCYear'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCQuarter'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCMonth'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCWeek'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'InCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'OutCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'TotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessTotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredTotalCount'}]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:17 2015] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:18 2015] [error] Saving chunk 5
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:18 2015] [error] Saving chunk 1
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:18 2015] [error] Saving chunk 11
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:18 2015] [error] Saving chunk 2
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Saving chunk 6
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Saving chunk 12
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Saving chunk 3
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Successfully pushed 906 entries to "8ae0a0b0-eee6-4062-8ef8-13f3177519ff".
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Saving chunk 7
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Saving chunk 13
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:19 2015] [error] Fetching from: http://hidden-domain.com/dataset/6449d8f5-76e7-4aff-bfb1-46d46542a56c/resource/8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a/download/footfallhourly.csv
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Saving chunk 14
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Saving chunk 8
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Deleting "8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a" from datastore.
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Saving chunk 9
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Determined headers and types: [{'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'Id'}, {'type': u'timestamp', 'id': u'Date'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'SiteName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationName'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'LocationGroup'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'WeekDay'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCYear'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCQuarter'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BRCMonth'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'BRCWeek'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'InCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'OutCount'}, {'type': u'numeric', 'id': u'TotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'BusinessTotalCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredInCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredOutCount'}, {'type': u'text', 'id': u'FactoredTotalCount'}]
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Saving chunk 15
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:21 2015] [error] Saving chunk 0
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Saving chunk 16
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Saving chunk 10
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]     retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 321, in push_to_datastore
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]     records, api_key, ckan_url)
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 150, in send_resource_to_datastore
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]     check_response(r, url, 'CKAN DataStore')
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]   File "/opt/ckan/ckan2.2.1/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 84, in check_response
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]     resp=pprint.pformat(json_response)))
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] JobError: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 409 Conflict. At: http://hidden-domain.com/api/3/action/datastore_create. Response: {u'error': {u'__type': u'Validation Error',
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]             u'constraints': [u'Cannot insert records or create index because of uniqueness constraint'],
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]             u'info': {u'orig': u'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"\\nDETAIL:  Key (typname, typnamespace)=(8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a__id_seq, 2200) already exists.\\n',
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]                       u'pgcode': u'23505'}},
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]  u'help': u'Adds a new table to the DataStore.\\n\\n    The datastore_create action allows you to post JSON data to be\\n    stored against a resource. This endpoint also supports altering tables,\\n    aliases and indexes and bulk insertion. This endpoint can be called multiple\\n    times to initially insert more data, add fields, change the aliases or indexes\\n    as well as the primary keys.\\n\\n    To create an empty datastore resource and a CKAN resource at the same time,\\n    provide ``resource`` with a valid ``package_id`` and omit the ``resource_id``.\\n\\n    If you want to create a datastore resource from the content of a file,\\n    provide ``resource`` with a valid ``url``.\\n\\n    See :ref:`fields` and :ref:`records` for details on how to lay out records.\\n\\n    :param resource_id: resource id that the data is going to be stored against.\\n    :type resource_id: string\\n    :param force: set to True to edit a read-only resource\\n    :type force: bool (optional, default: False)\\n    :param resource: resource dictionary that is passed to\\n        :meth:`~ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create`.\\n        Use instead of ``resource_id`` (optional)\\n    :type resource: dictionary\\n    :param aliases: names for read only aliases of the resource. (optional)\\n    :type aliases: list or comma separated string\\n    :param fields: fields/columns and their extra metadata. (optional)\\n    :type fields: list of dictionaries\\n    :param records: the data, eg: [{"dob": "2005", "some_stuff": ["a", "b"]}]  (optional)\\n    :type records: list of dictionaries\\n    :param primary_key: fields that represent a unique key (optional)\\n    :type primary_key: list or comma separated string\\n    :param indexes: indexes on table (optional)\\n    :type indexes: list or comma separated string\\n\\n    Please note that setting the ``aliases``, ``indexes`` or ``primary_key`` replaces the exising\\n    aliases or constraints. Setting ``records`` appends the provided records to the resource.\\n\\n    **Results:**\\n\\n    :returns: The newly created data object.\\n    :rtype: dictionary\\n\\n    See :ref:`fields` and :ref:`records` for details on how to lay out records.\\n\\n    ',
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error]  u'success': False}
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Saving chunk 17
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:22 2015] [error] Saving chunk 11
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:23 2015] [error] Saving chunk 18
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:23 2015] [error] Saving chunk 12
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:23 2015] [error] Saving chunk 19
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:23 2015] [error] Saving chunk 13
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:24 2015] [error] Saving chunk 14
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:24 2015] [error] Saving chunk 20
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:24 2015] [error] Saving chunk 15
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:24 2015] [error] Saving chunk 21
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:25 2015] [error] Saving chunk 16
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:25 2015] [error] Saving chunk 22
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 17
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 23
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 18
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 24
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 19
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:26 2015] [error] Saving chunk 25
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:27 2015] [error] Successfully pushed 6329 entries to "b9cde552-ff7a-41c3-b6e6-1f16a80a09eb".
[Thu Sep 17 17:20:27 2015] [error] Saving chunk 20
                           .... continues
[Thu Sep 17 17:24:29 2015] [error] Saving chunk 607
[Thu Sep 17 17:24:30 2015] [error] Successfully pushed 151896 entries to "8b71c43f-7e55-4926-ab06-39037026ce1a".
```

Comment: Several days of investigation is the reason my description is long, I'm also trying to include as much background as possible. My question states that I've confirmed my script is not at fault by carefully logging all API requests. I'm 100% confident that I'm sending only 3 update requests. The script itself is fairly basic and has been checked by several developers. Though suggestions on how to isolate it further would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally I'd be wary of using resource_update if there is a chance the resources are all in the same package.  Each time you call resource_update it then calls package_update (to make sure it is re-indexed).  If there is a new resource, OR it thinks the URL of any resources has changed - it'll trigger datapusher.

Better to use package_show, modify dict, and then package_update.

Comment: You can isolate this further by calling resource_update manually using curl whilst watching the DataPusher logs. The most helpful thing would be to write a failing test for DataPusher showing the spurious job being created.